# Counting and averaging words in sentences

Tags: python, tokenize, lexical-analysis

I must use Python to print the number of words and mean length of words in each sentence of a text file.  I cannot use NLTK or Regex for this assignment.

> The sentence in the file ends with a period, exclamation point, or question mark. A hyphen, dash, or apostrophe does not end a sentence. Quotation marks do not end a sentence. But also, some periods do not end sentences. For example, Mrs., Mr., Dr., Fr., Jr., St., are all commonly occurring abbreviations.

For example, if input text is:

```
"My name? Bob. Your name? Lily! Hi there"
```

...output should be:

```
[(no. of words, mean length of words in sentence1),
(no. of words, mean length of words in sentence2),
...]
```

The code:

```
p= ("Mrs.","Mr.","St.")
def punct_after_ab(texts):
    new_text = texts
    for abb in p:
        new_text = new_text.replace(abb,abb[:-1])
    return print(new_text)

import numpy
def word_list(text):
    special_characters = ["'",","]
    clean_text = text
    for string in special_characters:
        clean_text = clean_text.replace(string, "")
    count_list = [len(i) for i in clean_text.split()]
    count = [numpy.mean(count_list)]
    return print((count_list),(count))
```

But when I tested this, it does not split sentences.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Added my code but still looking for some guidance...

Comment: @Bala I updated my answer according to your updates

Answer (score 1):

Use something along the lines of `.split(' ')` to separate the words (in the stated case by spaces) and then use array operations and basic math/statistics to get your answers. If you update your question to be more specific and include some of your own code I would be willing to revise my answer accordingly.

You will find that on this site if you do not put much effort into the question you are asking, you aren't going to get very helpful answers. Try doing some research and writing as much code as you can before asking questions. This makes it much easier for people to help you and they will be more willing. As of right now it seems like you are just trying to get someone to do your homework for you.

> **Update:**

You code works for the most part, there's just some things you need to change. I played around with what you have and I was able to break the text down to arrays of sentences from which you could continue to run statistics on them.

input.txt:

```
My name? Mr. Bob. Your name? Mrs. Lily!
What's up?
```

test.py (I use python 3.6):

```
    def punct_after_ab(texts):
        p = ("Mrs.", "Mr.", "St.")
        new_text = texts
        for abb in p:
            new_text = new_text.replace(abb,abb[:-1])
        return new_text


    def clean_text(text):
        special_characters = ["'", ","]
        clean_text = text
        for string in special_characters:
            clean_text = clean_text.replace(string, "")
        return clean_text


    def split_sentence(text):
    #Initialize vars
    sentences = []
    start = 0
    i = 0

    # Loop through the text until you find punctuation,
    # then add the sentence to the final array
    for char in text:
        if char == '.':
            sentences.append(text[start:i+1])
            start = i + 2
        if char == '?':
            sentences.append(text[start:i+1])
            start = i + 2
        if char == '!':
            sentences.append(text[start:i+1])
            start = i + 2
        i += 1

    # Print the sentences to console
    for sentence in sentences:
        print(sentence)


def main():
    # Ask user for file name
    file = input("Enter file name: ")
    # Open the file and strip newline chars
    fd = open(file).read()
    fd = fd.strip("\n")

    # Remove punctuation that doesn't delineate sentences
    text = punct_after_ab(fd)
    text = clean_text(text)

    # Separate sentences
    split_sentence(text)

# Run program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I was able to get this to output the text below:

```
Enter file name: input.txt
My name?
Mr Bob.
Your name?
Mrs Lily!
Whats up?

Process finished with exit code 0
```

From there you can easily do your sentence statistics. I just put typed this up so you'll probably want to go through it and clean it up a bit. I hope this helps.

Comment: Could be, but I believe this is answering a much bigger problem for the user, as the question isn't specific enough for a legitimate answer.